# Identifying specific number in a string using python

Tags: python

I want to extract a number after every ":" (colon) in a string using python 3.5

my string is:

```
x= "RTD - Shanghai Indices - STD DLY - Indices - 11054 - ID:1053 (INACTIVE) RTD - SIX Swiss incl. SWX Europe - STD L1 - Equity - 10969 - ID:1096 (INACTIVE)"
```

I have used:

```
 re.findall('\d+', x)
```

but this returns all the number which is:

```
['11054', '1053', '1', '10969', '1096']
```

But the final result should be:

```
[1053, 1096]
```

Comment: have you tried adding the ":" like that re.findall(":\d+", x)

Comment: nope, but yes now i just got to know that would help, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre matching `\d+`, which is all numbers. If you want to match only numbers with a colon before it, add that to your regex: `:(\d+)`:

```
>>> import re
>>> x= "RTD - Shanghai Indices - STD DLY - Indices - 11054 - ID:1053 (INACTIVE) RTD - SIX Swiss incl. SWX Europe - STD L1 - Equity - 10969 - ID:1096 (INACTIVE)"
>>> re.findall(r':(\d+)', x)
['1053', '1096']
```

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
re.findall(':(\d+)', x)
```

Parentheses will match the group you want, and colon before that will match actual literal `:`. It will return digits which follow `:`.

```
>>> import re
>>> x= "RTD - Shanghai Indices - STD DLY - Indices - 11054 - ID:1053 (INACTIVE) RTD - SIX Swiss incl. SWX Europe - STD L1 - Equity - 10969 - ID:1096 (INACTIVE)"
>>> re.findall(':(\d+)', x)
['1053', '1096']
```

Answer (score 1):

Search for numbers following a `:` and convert to integer for your desired output: :

```
>>> [int(y) for y in re.findall(':(\d+)', x)]
[1053, 1096]
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
re.findall(r'(?<=\:)\d+', x)
```

Positive Lookbehind (?<=:)
Assert that the Regex below matches

: matches the character : literally (case sensitive)

\d+ matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed